# How do I change shortcut keys with autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, autohotkey, dvorak

I use a Dvorak keyboard. Shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl+x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> are hard to use, so is there any way to remap them to <kbd>ctrl+q</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+j</kbd>, and <kbd>ctrl+k</kbd> respectively, using AutoHotKey? Thanks!

Comment: In Windows and in all programs? One problem in doing this is that if i.e. ctrl+q is already bound to something, another place is needed to be found for thay key. In Mac OS X it is possible to change the keylayout to be dvorak but with qwerty shortcuts. Not sure this is possible in Windows. Personally I  think it is really confusing. When I think of `c` and `ctrl+c` I want it in the same location.

Comment: Yes and it is very easy. Just by reading the documentation you could do it.http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: I'm sorry. This was a waste of your time. I just entered the code wrong, and in all that time staring at it it just didn't register. Thanks for responding so promptly, though!

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward indeed, only to achieve the effect you want, you need to code it the opposite way:

```
^q::^x
^j::^c
^k::^v
```

It translates to `<what-keys-you-press>::<what-is-sent-instead>`.
Just be aware you may create a conflict, if some application happens to have these shortcuts defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty straight forward.

```
^x::^q
^c::^j
^v::^k
```

Note, this does not alter the behavior of the original shortcuts.  To do that you would have to remap those as well.  For more information, look at "remap keys or mouse buttons" in the help file.  It also describes a method for remapping keys somewhat more directly from the registry.

Comment: As @szczvr pointed out, the assignment is inverted: Ctrl+q needs to map to Ctrl+x, not the other way around.